# InDesign loading and saving joboptions file results in different files

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I received a .joboptions file from the printer, but I noticed when I load the file, then (without changing anything) save it as a different joboptions file, the files are different.

Here is a diff of the two files. Do any of these settings make a difference? If so, what? Am I safe to proceed using this slightly different file, since I presume behind the scenes that's how the file from the printer is being interpreted by InDesign?

Original loaded file:

```
/CalRGBProfile (eciRGB v2 ICCv4)
/DestinationProfileSelector /UseName
/PDFXOutputIntentProfileSelector /UseName
```

Saved file:

```
/CalRGBProfile (sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
/DestinationProfileSelector /WorkingCMYK
/PDFXOutputIntentProfileSelector /WorkingCMYK
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the specifications for .joboptions files in [Adobe® PDF Creation Settings](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFCreationSettings_v9.pdf).
It turns out that in my case these options do not make a difference since I am working in CMYK anyway.